# SQLite Ruby Gem not working with string placeholders

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

So, I have this code here:

`database.execute("SELECT * FROM #{table} WHERE id=#{id}")`

But every time I run it I get 
`unrecognized token: "]" (SQLite3::SQLException)`
I've tried using different ways of using placeholders, but they dont work.
I have tried replaceing the placeholders with strings and then running the SQL query, and it works like it should.

Comment: Print the contents of `table` and `id` before you run the query. The problem is very likely that those two variables contain character that are not allowed in a query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might know it is wrong with the two variables.
The controlling of variable is an important method for debugging.

So just print the `table` and `id` before executing the SQL, which may not be what you expect.